# Pandas organize merge information in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Folks, I am merging specific informations into a dataframe in a loop, but it is not forming like i want.

Here is the code:`

```
for file in csv_files:
      
    arqs = pd.read_excel(file)
    
    for i in range(len(arqs.columns)):
        titulos.append(Conv_Num_Str(i+1))
    arqs.columns=[titulos]
    titulos.clear()
    
    PLDV_Nome_torre = arqs[Nome_torre[0]].iloc[int(Nome_torre[1])-2:int(Nome_torre[1])-1]
    Tabela_Dados_Localizados1= pd.concat([Tabela_Dados_Localizados,PLDV_Nome_torre])
    
    try:
        PLDV_Tipo_torre = arqs[Tipo_torre[0]].iloc[int(Tipo_torre[1])-2:int(Tipo_torre[1])-1]
        Tabela_Dados_Localizados = pd.concat([Tabela_Dados_Localizados,PLDV_Tipo_torre])
    except: pass
    try:
        PLDV_Progressiva_torre = arqs[Progressiva_torre[0]].iloc[int(Progressiva_torre[1])-2:int(Progressiva_torre[1])-1]
        Tabela_Dados_Localizados = pd.concat([Tabela_Dados_Localizados,PLDV_Progressiva_torre])
    except: pass
```

the output is Bening like

```
            E          I
4    2/1=MV01        NaN
6        JJAA        NaN
4         NaN   2093.374
4   9/2=MV01C        NaN
6        JJSP        NaN
4         NaN   9883.078
4  13/2=MV01D        NaN
6        JJSP        NaN
4         NaN  13860.772
```

But i want `

```
            E          I        J
4    2/1=MV01        JJAA    2093.374
4   9/2=MV01C        JJSP    9883.078 
4  13/2=MV01D        JJSP    13860.772
```

Comment: Could you edit so we can see a sample of what the CSV files look like?

Comment: Henry, the informations come right they are in the cells. E6, E4 anda I4. I tried to reset de index, but didnt work

Comment: Without being able to look at the data the best I can guess is to try concating by a different axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to restructure the output to the desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['E'].combine_first(df['I']).values.reshape(-1,3), columns = ['E', 'I', 'J'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
            E     I          J
0    2/1=MV01  JJAA   2093.374
1   9/2=MV01C  JJSP   9883.078
2  13/2=MV01D  JJSP  13860.772
```